# USS720 (usb to parallel port) as GPIO

Tags: linux

I have a Belkin F5U002 usb to parallel cable that I want to have a second "crack" at using for GPIO. (I failed the first time.)

It's based on Lucent's USS720 and has a printer and "register" mode, with the register mode allowing for GPIO use.

Source: http://www.linux-usb.org/USB-guide/x532.html

Basically, under linux the "uss720" kernel module allows for emulating a conventional parallel port, albeit somewhat slowly and with lag.

Well, I don't know to load that kernel module (I'm thinking it's baked into the kernel itself after so many years) and no extra modules seem to get loaded when I plug it in.

Debian does create "lp0" under "/dev/usb/", but thats the standard parallel printer driver.

No, it does NOT show up under "/proc/sys/dev/parport". Only the standard dummy "default" one is there.

Answer (score 0):

Wait, I think I got it!

Basically, I forgot "modprobe" existed.

modprobe -r uss720
modprobe -r usblp
modprobe uss720

Unloads "usblp" and reloads "uss720". Now "parport0" exists under "/proc/sys/dev/parport".

Edit: And... I still cant read or write to the device... F***.

The issue seems to be some weird hardware/software incompatibility...